# How to superscript in PHP only two decimals after the dot

Tags: explode, superscript, decimal

I have this code:

```
<?php echo $price; ?>
```

which gives me this result:

```
1,500.99
```

This code works like a charm to superscript the numbers after the dot:

```
$parts = explode('.', $price); 
echo "$parts[0].<sup>$parts[1]</sup>";
```

but if I have a price like this: 1,500.99€ it superscripts the € sign as well. Can this be stoped? Not to superscript it if it's not a number, or to superscript only 2 characters after the dot?

It doesn't need to be the same code, if you have something else, I'll give it a try.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions may be a little more flexible:

```
<?php
$price = "1,500.99";
$pattern = '/([\d,]+\.)(\d+)(.*)$/';
// ...or '/([\d\.]+,)(\d+)(.*)$/' if your currencies are 1.500,00

$formatted = preg_replace($pattern, '$1<sup>$2</sup>$3', $price);
// gives "1,500<sup>.99</sup>"

$price = "1,500.99€";

$formatted = preg_replace($pattern, '$1<sup>$2</sup>$3', $price);
// gives "1,500<sup>.99</sup>€"
```

Comment: Just one quick question :) What should I change in the above code, if the deliminator is a comma? :) Thanks.

Comment: Edited with second example in the comment for currencies in the format `1.500,00`